Interpretation of syntactic network generated through udpipe_annotate from udpipe package in R
I am trying to do syntactic network analysis in R using udpipe for speech data.
Below is sample data stored in ordered.txt file.
What is your name?
What is my name?
My name was Neeraj.

Below is my code snippet:
# Load the libraries
library(udpipe)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

# Load the transcript (Assuming you have already read the text into a variable)
transcript <- readLines("ordered.txt")

# Preprocess the text: clean up and tokenize (You can modify the cleaning as per your needs)
transcript_clean <- gsub("(unintelligible|\\.|\\?|,|!|:)", "", transcript)  # Remove punctuation and unintelligible markers

# Load a pre-trained English model for syntactic parsing
ud_model <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
udpipe_model <- udpipe_load_model(ud_model$file_model)

# Perform syntactic parsing
parsed_transcript <- udpipe_annotate(udpipe_model, x = transcript_clean)
parsed_df <- as.data.frame(parsed_transcript)

# Check the syntactic parsing result
head(parsed_df)

# Create a syntactic network using the head dependencies
edges <- parsed_df[!is.na(parsed_df$head_token_id), c("token", "head_token_id", "dep_rel")]
colnames(edges) <- c("from", "to", "relation")

# Build a graph
syntactic_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = TRUE)

# Visualize the syntactic network
ggraph(syntactic_graph, layout = "fr") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(label = relation), arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm'))) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), vjust = 1, hjust = 1) +
  theme_minimal()

This code generates the networks as shown below.

In this code, edges are created using parsed_df, specifically using the columns token, head_token_id, and dep_rel. However, I am not able to interpret the network properly. In the lower right corner, the nodes what and neeraj are connected to a node named 0 (for root), where head_token_id was 0, since these two words are syntactically not dependent on any other word. Further, udpipe_annotate does Lemmatisation of text and as a result derived words are converted to their base form, example, is and was are both converted to their base form which is "be". However, in the network they are all seperate nodes. How do I fix this ?
Also, in the lower left corner, I see My connected to a node labeled as 2, while I was expecting "my" to be connected to the word node "name" as shown in the output screenshot of parsed_df below.

